# I need an example of a function with these properties.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a problem that says $A$ is finite and $B\subset A$ and that $G$ is the subset set of $S_A$ consisting of all the permutations $f$ of $A$ s.t. $f(x)\in B \ \forall \ x\in B$.

these functions are bijections on B because it is finite, and we have that 1-1 gives us onto, but I am trying to think of an example where if we didnt have that A was finite, then we might not necessarily have that they are bijections on B.

Can someone think of a good example?

Comment: Presumably, $S_A$ is the set of all permutations of $A$, aka bijections $\sigma:A\to A$. I think you can show that if $B$ or $A\setminus B$ is finite, then any element of $\S_A$ which sends all elements of $B$ to elements of $B$ will restrict to a bijection on $B$...

Comment: So you need $A$ infinite, and $B\subset A$ with $B$ and $A\setminus B$ infinite to get a counterexample. Try $A=\mathbb N$ and $B=2\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

To give a simple example, let $A = \mathbb Q$, $B = \mathbb Z$ and $f\colon\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$, $x \mapsto 2x$. Then $f[\mathbb Z] = 2\mathbb Z \subsetneq \mathbb Z$.